# Use USB Iphone tethering for Macbook and use AirPort for Printer

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, airport, tethering

I already set up the iPhone tethering to have Internet on my Macbook via the iPhone phone-line. I'm using it via USB because I want to use the Wifi from the AirPort for a connection with my printer - which works as well.

The problem is: It won't work at the same time, leaving me offline as soon as I connect the AirPort with the printer. It seems like that my Macbook prefers the AirPort for Internet, but doesn't recognize that my printer is no internet-connection. So the iPhone tethering is still on, but I don't have internet access...

Anyone with a solution for this specific problem ?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the service order for the wifi to be below the USB tether. Apple provides instructions here:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18458?locale=en_US

Simply drag the Wifi entry down below the USB or the USB up above the wifi.

Comment: Just realized I answered a really old question, oh well :)